# How is the constant in Marsaglia's xorshift* RNG determined?

Tags: random-generation, xorshift

I get Marsaglia's basic xorshift RNG.  For further randomness he suggests multiplying the result by a "suitable constant."  This is some code I've found that does just that:

```
uint64_t s[ 16 ]; 
int p;

uint64_t next(void) { 
    uint64_t s0 = s[ p ];
    uint64_t s1 = s[ p = ( p + 1 ) & 15 ];
    s1 ^= s1 << 31; // a
    s1 ^= s1 >> 11; // b
    s0 ^= s0 >> 30; // c
    return ( s[ p ] = s0 ^ s1 ) * 1181783497276652981LL; 
}
```

Where does the 1181783497276652981LL come from?  It seems to me that just any number isn't a suitable constant.  If just any number won't work, how is it determined?

*As always, I apologize if someone has asked this and it's been answered elsewhere.  I did search and couldn't find what I needed.*

Comment: Where does he make the suggestion? Full reference if possible.

Comment: **Xorshift RNGs**  
George Marsaglia  
2003-07-04  
_Journal of Statistical Software_  
Vol. 8, Issue 14, Jul 2003 Abstract: Description of a class of simple, extremely fast random number generators (RNGs) with periods 2k - 1 for k = 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192. These RNGs seem to pass tests of randomness very well.  
[PDF](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper)  
  
There's more to be found here:  
**An experimental exploration of Marsaglia’s xorshift generators, scrambled**  
Sebastiano Vigna  
[PDF](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/xorshift.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

That's my code :). The link above explains why I chose that constant, but, basically, it's a constant that yields a good multiplicative congruential generator. As such, it is expected to scramble in a nice way the bits of the number it is multiplied by. This is just a heuristic borrowed from "Numerical Recipes". The paper has more details.